# Does ADL work for the global namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, using, argument-dependent-lookup, global-namespace

[Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5076640/321013) [such as](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.c++.moderated/1Qz71aFnXlI/Gd71gwRaWssJ) enabling outputting of `std` types explain how [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) can be used to "inject" a certain function/operator, depending on the type the fn/op is applied to.

I was wondering wheter ADL fully applies to the global namespace, that is, whether a type declared (or made available via `using`) at [global namespace scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10269085/321013) makes ADL look for matching functions in the global namespace?

Specifically, are these equivalent wrt. ADL?:

```
// 1 - at global namespace scope
struct GlobalType {};

template< class Ch, class Tr>
std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os, GlobalType const& x)
{
    os << ...;
    return os;
} 

// 2 - within namespace
namespace ecaps {

    struct EcapsType {};

    template< class Ch, class Tr>
    std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os, EcapsType const& x)
    {
        os << ...;
        return os;
    } 

}

// 3 - Type brought to global NS via using, function at global scope
namespace other {
    struct OtherType {};    
}

using other::OtherType;

template< class Ch, class Tr>
std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os, OtherType const& x)
{
    os << ...;
    return os;
}
```

---

Wrt. global namespace scope not needing ADL: (update after a now deleted answer)

One [Daniel Krügler of Committee fame describes an ADL problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.c++.moderated/1Qz71aFnXlI/Gd71gwRaWssJ) as such:

> This unqualified call has the effect that unqualified name lookup
>   happens and as a consequence of this, the compiler searches for the
>   name `operator<<`. beginning **from the lexical location where the
>   `operator<<` call is found "upwards"** (...) starting in the current namespace and all the
>   namespaces that include that namespace (including the global
>   namespace, btw.) and - ...

Emph. mine. Note how the outer namespaces are described to only be considered "... *from the lexical location* ...". He continues:

> ... and - as a second route - it performs a second phase of this
>   lookup the compiler searches in the so-called associated namespaces of
>   the argument types occurring in this call.
>
> In the presented example, the first phase of the search fails, because
>   at the point where `#include <iterator>` exists, there is no
>   corresponding `operator<<` for these argument types in any namespace.
>   Note that your declaration of `operator<<` is provided lexically *after*
>   the point where the call of `operator<<` happens somewhere in some of
>   the library headers. **The second phase of the search would also
>   consider locations that
>   *follow* the actual function call**, but only within the associated namespaces.

Bold emph. mine. So it would seem to me it *is* relevant that ADL works for the global namespace. Of course I could easily have misunderstood something.

---

Note: This *may* be a case of the standard simply not explicitly mentioning it one way or another, because the global NS is just like any other namespace -- then again it may not, my knowledge of the Standard is very limited.

Comment: No need for ADL, since global functions are already available.

Comment: @BЈовић - see ongoing edits

Comment: I don't understand what exactly the problem is. Can you create an example, where a function from global namespace is not considered?

Answer (score 4):

**Completely forget my initial answer, it was plain wrong.**

From the C++11 standard, §3.4.2 on ADL (emphasis mine):

> When the postfix-expression in a function call (5.2.2) is an
>   unqualified-id, other namespaces **not considered during the usual
>   unqualified lookup** (3.4.1) may be searched, and in those namespaces,
>   namespace-scope friend function declarations (11.3) not otherwise
>   visible may be found.

So in short, since unqualified lookup will always search in the global namespace, **ADL will *never* apply to global namespace**.

Comment: @MartinBa In Daniel's example, namespace std will not *also* be considered in the second phase of lookup (i.e. during ADL), it will *only* be considered then, since it is not an enclosing namespace of the site calling the function in question.

Comment: N3337 / 14.6.4.2 : "For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces (3.4.2), only function declarations found in **either the template definition context** or the template instantiation context are found." - so I say your interpretation of 3.4.2 is wrong.