# C++ can't find function out of namespace

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, name-lookup

Compiling the following code fails because the second function can't find the first one, even though it's outside namespaces. I couldn't figure out the problem myself, and so far I haven't found any answers on the net.

test.cpp:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

struct myclass {};

template <typename T, typename U>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, const std::pair<T, U> &p) {
    os << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")";
    return os;
}

namespace my {
    void operator<< (std::ostream os, myclass m) {
        std::cout << std::pair<int, int>(5, 4); // This is line 13.
    }
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Error given by the compiler (`g++ test.cpp -O2 -o test.exe`):
`test.cpp:13:13: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'std::pair<int, int>')`.
And it goes on, giving a long list of suggestions for what `operator<<` could have meant.

**Observation 1:** If the two functions differ in name, no error occurs.
**Observation 2:** If `namespace my {` `}` is removed, no error occurs.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133383/does-adl-work-for-the-global-namespace

Comment: By explicitly calling the global operator: `::operator<<(std::cout, std::pair<int, int>(5, 4));` it should work, but that's mighty ugly (and un-chainable). I won't post that as an answer in case there's a better way.

Comment: The better way is to use a using directive before the call (`using ::operator<<;`). As to why the lookup doesn't end up finding the canidate in global namespace...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a kind of name hiding; functions/operators can't be overloaded through different scopes.

According to the rule of [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup),

(emphasis mine)

> ..., name lookup examines the scopes as described below, until **it finds at least one declaration of any kind, at which time the lookup stops and no further scopes are examined**.

For this case, the name `operator<<` is found at the scope of namespace `my` (i.e. itself), then name lookup stops, the global scope won't be examined, the global `operator<<` won't be considered for the following overload resolution.

And

> Observation 1: If the two functions differ in name, no error occurs.

It's fine because there's no name hiding.

> Observation 2: If namespace my { } is removed, no error occurs.

It's fine because the two `operator<<` is put at the same scope, i.e. the global namespace. Then both `operator<<` could be found and then considered at overload resolution, the appropriate one will be selected at last.

As the comments suggested, you can apply `using` to introduce the names in global namespace into namespace `my`; then both `operator<<` will be found and then considered in overload resolution.

Answer (score 2):

The `operator<<` defined in `namespace my` prevents overload resolution to consider your `operator<<` defined in the global namespace. You can only rely on ADL here or bring the desired overload in the current scope:

```
namespace my {

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, myclass m) {
    // Bringing the operator in the global namespace in the current scope
    using ::operator<<;
    std::cout << std::pair<int, int>(5, 4);
}

}
```

Comment: or more explicitly: `::operator<<(std::cout, std::pair<int, int>{ 5, 4 });`

Comment: I prefer the using solution as it still allows ADL