# Using std::less<> for unique_ptr to raw pointer comparison fails to compile, but works with wrapper?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I want to search by raw pointer in a set of `std::unique_ptr`, and instead of writing my own comparator class I decided to use the transparent property of `std::less<>`.

Here's an example code based on the [cppreference example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find#Example).

This doesn't compile:

```
#include <memory>
#include <set>

using FatKey = std::unique_ptr<int>;
using LightKey = int;

bool operator<(const FatKey& fk, LightKey* lk) { return fk.get() < lk; }
bool operator<(LightKey* lk, const FatKey& fk) { return lk < fk.get(); }
bool operator<(const FatKey& fk1, const FatKey& fk2) { return fk1.get() < fk2.get(); }

int main()
{  
    std::set<FatKey, std::less<>> example2;
 
    LightKey lk = 2;
    auto search2 = example2.find(&lk);
}
```

While this works fine:

```
#include <memory>
#include <set>

template<typename T>
struct UPtrWrapper { std::unique_ptr<T> ptr; };

using FatKey = UPtrWrapper<int>;
using LightKey = int;

bool operator<(const FatKey& fk, LightKey* lk) { return fk.ptr.get() < lk; }
bool operator<(LightKey* lk, const FatKey& fk) { return lk < fk.ptr.get(); }
bool operator<(const FatKey& fk1, const FatKey& fk2) { return fk1.ptr.get() < fk2.ptr.get(); }

int main()
{  
    std::set<FatKey, std::less<>> example2;
 
    LightKey lk = 2;
    auto search2 = example2.find(&lk);
}
```

The `FatKey` is passed by const ref in both cases, they are both template classes, neither of them is copy constructible, but still only one of them works.

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829319/c-cant-find-function-out-of-namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `std::unique_ptr<int>` nor `int` involve user-defined types; in terms of ADL their associated namespaces are `namespace std` only.

When you use a wrapper type you have an associated namespace of the root namespace (the namespace where you declared the wrapper), which means that ADL can find the free `operator<`s defined there.

Indeed, this is a Good Thing since it prevents someone else writing their own `operator<(int*, std::unique_ptr<int> const&)` which might have a different behavior to yours.

Comment: "*which is, to be clear, not actually OK since you shouldn't inherit from standard library types*" The OP didn't use inheritance. Unless there was an older version of the question that did.

Comment: @NicolBolas oops, yeah. Fixing.

Answer (score -1):

ecatmur already answered that the first example didn't work due to ADL.

I just want to show how you can create your `std::set` without needing all these extra functions:

```
auto PtrCmp = [](std::unique_ptr<int> const & lhs,
    std::unique_ptr<int> const & rhs) {
  return lhs.get() < rhs.get();
};

auto orderedPtrSet = std::set<std::unique_ptr<int>, decltype(PtrCmp)>(PtrCmp);
```

*Note:* I realize this is not a real answer to the question, but it's a little too long to put in a comment. And it seems to me it might be interesting for OP.

Comment: I downvoted this for two reasons: default-constructible stateless lambdas have only been introduced in C++20, and my question was about transparent comparators for comparing `unique_ptr`s by identity, not by value

Comment: @BalázsKovacsics Ah, I didn't notice I had my compiler set to C++20. I also missed you were comparing the pointers themselves. The example now compares correctly and works for C++14.